# grep --output-only onto single line

Tags: linux, grep

I'm currently running a grep that is very close to what I want:

```
$grep ! myinput_file/* | grep  -Po '\d+\.\d+|\d+'
```

I like that this command only returns the matching contents of the line, but want the output to be on a line by line basis. E.g. when I run the command currently I get:

```
7.969
80
2
152.03886767
7.969
80
4
152.10112473
7.969
80
6
152.10200398
7.969
80
8
152.10203172
```

Where I would rather get output of the form:

```
7.969 80 2 152.03886767
7.969 80 4 152.10112473
7.969 80 6 152.10200398
7.969 80 8 152.10203172
```

I could write a script or use vim on the output, but I suspect there is a more elegant solution...

PS the source file looks like:

```
$grep ! encutkpoint_calculations/* | grep  -P '\d+\.\d+|\d+'

encutkpoint_calculations/MgO.scf.a=7.969.ecut=80.k=2.out:!    total energy              =    -152.03886767 Ry
encutkpoint_calculations/MgO.scf.a=7.969.ecut=80.k=4.out:!    total energy              =    -152.10112473 Ry
encutkpoint_calculations/MgO.scf.a=7.969.ecut=80.k=6.out:!    total energy              =    -152.10200398 Ry
encutkpoint_calculations/MgO.scf.a=7.969.ecut=80.k=8.out:!    total energy              =    -152.10203172 Ry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since data is being extracted from file names as well, I'll leave the first use of `grep` as is

```sh
$ # this won't depend on knowing how many matches are found per line
$ # this would also work if there are different number of matches per line
$ grep '!' encutkpoint_calculations/* | perl -lne 'print join " ", /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g'
7.969 80 2 152.03886767
7.969 80 4 152.10112473
7.969 80 6 152.10200398
7.969 80 8 152.10203172
```

Alternate is to post process the data, if number of matches is constant per line

```sh
grep '!' encutkpoint_calculations/* | grep -oP '\d+(\.\d+)?' | pr -4ats' '
```